# What would be a correct way of running a custom Parse Cloud Code function from Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, .net-3.5

I'm following the [Cloud Code Guide from Parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide) and got to the point of successfully uploading a script with a sample function called "hello" to the cloud. The function returns string "hello world" when you call it.

Now I have to run it, and this is where I stumble: there is no example available on how to do that from Unity C# environment. There are examples for curl, iOS applications, JS and so on, but not for that environment.

The closest one is a "Windows" example, I guess, which reads like this:

```
var result = await ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IDictionary<string, object>>("hello", new Dictionary<string, object>());
```

Except Unity only has .NET 3.5 features, so there is no async. And except this example is not covering how to extract the actual response like examples for other platforms do.

Parse asset package for Unity adds [it's own solution for the async problem called Tasks](https://www.parse.com/docs/unity_guide#tasks), so I guess I should just use that, just like in Unity Guide examples on standard functions like queries. I guess I can call my "hello" function and read it's "hello world" response using this code:

```
var helloTask = ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<IDictionary<string, object>> ("hello", new Dictionary<string, object> ()).ContinueWith (t =>
{
    IDictionary<string, object> result = t.Result;
    if (result != null)
    {
        string response = (string) result["result"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (response))
            Debug.Log (response);
    }
});
```

It did not work, of course, or I would not be asking that question. No errors, but no log either. I modified the code above to warn me in the log if string above is indeed null or empty, or if result object is null, but I'm not getting any messages even in that case, which leads me to assume I'm using ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync completely incorrectly, with anything past ContinueWith not even being called.

What would be the correct way of calling a custom Cloud Code function from Unity then?